# C++, how to cast derived class to protected base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, base-class, class-visibility

I need to cast a class to its protected base:

```
class ComplicatedOne : public Object {
    //Lots of funcs I don't want or need.
};

class Line : protected ComplicatedOne {
    //Some funcs of ComplicatedOne get re-implemented or called by alias here
};

class Array {
    void Add (Object &obj);
};

main() {
    Array a;
    a.Add(new Line());
}
```

I need to add a `Line` to an `Array` but the `Object` base is not visible. Should I re-impliment its methods publicly or is there an implicit cast operator I could override?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this, you're telling the compiler that you can't implicitly convert a `Line` to an `Object`:

```
class Line : protected Object {
};
```

But it seems to me that you want to do this, and also that you should do this. So make the inheritance public. This is a design question.

Don't make the inheritance `protected` just to keep methods in the base class `protected`.

One other option is to implement the cast operator in Line:

```
class Line : protected Object 
{
public:
   operator Object&();
};
```

and call the function like so:

```
a.Add(Line());
```

instead of

```
a.Add(new Line());
```

You can't implicitly cast pointers in this situation. However I suggest changing the inheritance type.

Answer (score 2):

Only friends and subclasses of `Line` can perform this cast. You could do this:

```
class Line : protected Object {
    friend class Array;
};

class Array {
public:
    template<class T>
    void Add (T &obj) {
        add_impl(obj); // cast is accessible here, because Array is a friend 
                       // of Line
    }

private:
    void add_impl(Obj &obj);
};
```

You don't have to use a function-template there, but I assumed you have more classes that derive from `Object` in this way, so a template would be helpful there.

Comment: I could extend `Array` like you advise but aren't there solutions more closely approximating my proposed ones? Ie the implicit cast operator would be perfect.

Comment: By making the inheritance protected you are explicitly forbidding an implicit cast. This is contradictory.